# How to release partial DLL in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, managed

I am used to deliver DLLs that built on top of several static libraries(.lib) in the unmanaged environment. Now I need to do similar thing but most lower level libraries are already managed DLLs. For security reasons, I don't want include every functions in these managed libraries. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's your DLL, you get to decide what you're going to expose by using the `public`, `private`, `protected` and `internal` modifiers.

Comment: On the compiler level, useful but limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much you can do here. Your choices are:

1. Obfuscate the lower level libraries. You still ship all functions, but they are harder to decompile.
2. Refactor the libaries into different assemblies, so you can ship them more granularly.